# Open-closed topology on the real numbers

Tags: general-topology

I am reading a paper which refers to

> the topological space
> $(\mathbb{R}^+, \tau)$ where $\tau$ is the closed-open topology on $\mathbb{R}^+$ generated by the set of intervals $[s, t)$ with $s \leq t$ as its basis.

- What does it mean to call something a closed-open topology, as opposed to a topology? I can't find any definition of a closed-open topology.
- What does it mean to say that $s \leq t$ is its basis? According to wikipedia, ''a basis for a topology on a set $X$ is a family $B$ of open subsets of $X$ such that every open set is equal to a union of some sub-family of $B$''. But I can't see how defining the basis as $s \leq t$ fits this definition.

Comment: The collection of all intervals of the form $[s,t)$ where $s\le t$ is a basis of a topology on $\mathbb R^+$. This topology on $\mathbb R^+$ is called the "closed-open topology".

Comment: @timon92 Could you perhaps specify in more detail what this topology is in an answer? Is it called the closed-open topology because everything in it is both open and closed? So is $\tau$ a set whose members are all in the range of $[s, t)$ for $s,t \in \mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: @timon92 Is it this topology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology

Comment: It is not the case that all sets in this topology are both closed and open. The topology is given that name because its basis consists of intervals of the form $[s,t)$ (you may think of them as closed- from-the-left, open-from-the-right intervals)

Comment: yes it is exactly this topology!

Comment: @timon92 Just for clarification, by ''all sets in this topology'' do you mean all sets in $\tau$? Can you given an example of a member of $\tau$ which is not closed?

Comment: For instance, $A=(1,2)\in \tau$ is a set that is not closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, suppose $X$ is a set, and $\mathcal{B}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ such that $X=\cup_{B\in\mathcal{B}} B$, and which satisfy the following property: for all $B_1, B_2\in\mathcal{B}$ and for all $x\in B_1\cap B_2$ there is some $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$. In this case we can define $\tau\subseteq 2^X$ like this:

$\tau=\{U\subseteq X: \forall x\in U \ \ \exists B\in\mathcal{B} $ such that $x\in B\subseteq U\}$

It's not hard to check that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$. And then note that $\mathcal{B}$ is its basis. Indeed, if $U\in\tau$ then by definition for every $x\in U$ there is some $B_x\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B_x\subseteq U$. Thus $U=\cup_{x\in U} B_x$.

So in your case we have $X=\mathbb{R^+}$ and $\mathcal{B}=\{[s,t): 0\leq s\leq t\}$. This collection indeed satisfies the required property, so it generates a topology on $\mathbb{R^+}$. The author calls it the closed-open topology.